# Find the measure of the smallest angle that determine the diagonals of a quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference: Calculate the measure of the smallest angle that determine the diagonals of a quadrilateral, inscribed in a circle, if the sides and are equivalent to the sides of the equilateral triangle and regular pentagon, inscribed in said circle. (Answer:$6^o$)

My progress:

I made the drawing and put the information that I could deduce

[image]

$\theta=?\\L_3=r\sqrt3\\
cos72=sin18= \frac{\sqrt5-1}{4}\\
cos36 = sin54 = \frac{\sqrt5+1}{4}\\
L_5=2rcos54 = \frac{\sqrt10-2\sqrt5}{4}$

I don't know if the way is this way

[image]

Comment: What does "the smallest angle that determine the diagonals" mean?

Comment: As for $\theta$,

$$\begin{align*}
\angle ADB &= \angle AOB/2 = 60^\circ\\
\angle CAD &= \angle COD/2 = 36^\circ\\
\theta &= 180^\circ - \angle ADP - \angle PAD\\
&= \ldots
\end{align*}$$

Comment: @peterwhy  Thanks...I really don't know where they get 6 degrees as an answer

Comment: @petaarantes, I do not see any equilateral triangle in your figure. may be you mean isosceles. Also I could not get your statement. can you explain what exactly you mean.

Comment: @sirous   Triangle ABC is equilateral. I need to find $\theta$, the smallest angle between the diagonals of quadrilateral ABCD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Comment: as you see in figure if triangle is equilateral then minimum of $\theta$ is ($\theta=24^o$)(triangle  DEF and quadrilateral FIJE). ($\theta=6^o$) is possible if triangle is isosceles(quadrilateral BCIJ) in this case one side of quadrilateral is the base of isosceles triangle  ABC.

Comment: @petaarantes , De nada